# How to find a given date is in the array of set of dates?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have  set of dates in array format just like below

```
[
 ["2018-10-15T18:30:00.000Z","2018-10-15T18:30:00.000Z"],
 ["2018-10-23T18:30:00.000Z","2018-10-25T18:30:00.000Z"],
 ["2018-10-28T18:30:00.000Z","2018-10-29T18:30:00.000Z"]
]
```

I used this array for date range selection. ie, user select date ranges of `oct 15`, `oct 23-25`, `oct 28-29`.

I want to find a given date is in the part of the above selection. and returns the index of the selected date range. for example, If I pass `Oct 15`, then it is part of the selection so output will be index 0, If I give `OCT 24`, then it also part of the selection `OCT 23-25` and output will be index 1. if I give `Nov 1`, then it is not part of the select output out put will be `-1`.

So my question is how can I achieve this with an optimized solution. What I am done so far is

```
function getIndexOfDate(dateSelected = [], currentDate) {
  for (i = 0; i < dateSelected.length; i++) {
    if(checkDateIsPartOfDateRange(dateSelected[i],currentDate)){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1
}


function checkDateIsPartOfDateRange(dateRange = [], date) {
  startDate = dateRange[0];
  endDate = dateRange[1]
  if (date.getTime() >= startDate.getTime() && date.getTime() <= endDate.getTime()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I don't know, but  I think this  is not an optimized solution, There may be another way to do this. Please suggest me one.

Comment: If you can store the data as an object with the dates as keys it may be easier/ faster to find. Not sure if it works for you but maybe give it a try.

Comment: The dates are saved as date object. what you mean by dates as keys. I am sorry I didn't understand that.

Comment: I dont mean the date, i mean `the data` like your set of dates which is now an array:)

Comment: Okay. I got that. But In  my case I need this  array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the dates in your array are in ISO 8601 format, you can just use string comparison to compare them (as long as no timezone information is present).

You can then use [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with a callback function to get the index in the array:

```
const getIndex = (dates, d) => dates.findIndex(([s, e]) => d >= s && d <= e);
```

---

Here's a complete snippet:

```js
const dates = [
 ["2018-10-15T18:30:00.000Z","2018-10-15T18:30:00.000Z"],
 ["2018-10-23T18:30:00.000Z","2018-10-25T18:30:00.000Z"],
 ["2018-10-28T18:30:00.000Z","2018-10-29T18:30:00.000Z"]
];

const getIndex = (dates, d) => dates.findIndex(([s, e]) => d >= s && d <= e);

console.log(getIndex(dates, '2018-10-24T12:00:00.000Z')); // 1
console.log(getIndex(dates, '2018-10-26T12:00:00.000Z')); // -1
```

Same snippet if using `Date` objects:

```js
const dates = [
 [new Date("2018-10-15T18:30:00.000Z"),new Date("2018-10-15T18:30:00.000Z")],
 [new Date("2018-10-23T18:30:00.000Z"),new Date("2018-10-25T18:30:00.000Z")],
 [new Date("2018-10-28T18:30:00.000Z"),new Date("2018-10-29T18:30:00.000Z")]
];

const getIndex = (dates, d) => dates.findIndex(([s, e]) => d >= s && d <= e);

console.log(getIndex(dates, new Date('2018-10-24T12:00:00.000Z'))); // 1
console.log(getIndex(dates, new Date('2018-10-26T12:00:00.000Z'))); // -1
```

Comment: Whenever dealing with dates, please do Date comparison and not string. [Ref - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7503w6L/)

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you for your feedback. Your reference fiddle produces correct results as far as I can tell. Why would string comparison be a problem when using correctly formatted ISO 8601 dates (without timezone information)?

Comment: @Rajesh or timestamps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I run some performance testing. Both solution have same time if array is smaller. but if there are lot of date range suppose 50 to 100 comparing the solution my solution runs faster(not so faster,only by avg 1 millisecond :) ) . But I think the 'less code' is an advantage for this answer.so +1 from my side

Comment: The number-based comparison should always be faster. If you have date objects to work with, you might as well use the date objects in the comparison, instead of using strings.

Comment: Yes . I have date objects

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen *when using correctly formatted ISO 8601 dates* This is a big IF. Date comparisons as string are usually nightmare. Date operations are also crazy. Hence `moment` exists. But considering the fact that this is an opinionated comment, I suggested an alternative

Comment: @Rajesh Agree on string-based date comparison being a mess, that's why I explicitly specified ISO 8601 format without timezone information. Regardless, my function works fine when passed date objects instead of strings, and I've added a snippet to demonstrate this.

Comment: its working for dates also. This is what I want.Thank you

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Just fyi, in `d >= s`, comparison is still made on string and date object will be converted to default format that is different for browsers/timezone. Hence I used `+d` which is a shorthand for `date.getTime()`

Comment: @Rajesh Agree. When dealing with `Date` objects, the coercion to a number using `+` is better because the comparison is likely to be faster. But, I'm not aware of any current browser that returns a date string format that is not lexically comparable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getTime()` function to convert date to timestamp then you can compare those to find a match

```
    function findDateFromArray(dates,date) {
      return dates.findIndex((elem) => {
        return elem.getTime() === date.getTime()
      })
    }

    console.log(findDateFromArray(dates,date))
```

Comment: This does not check whether the date is between the specified start and end dates, however.

Comment: crashing.. Not working. I think elem.getTime() === date.getTime() won't work with date range